# Mockito 3 any() Strict stubbing argument mismatch

Tags: java, mockito, stub

I'm using Mockito 3.1.0.

I'm trying to Mock my method with this syntax:

```java
when(mockedObject.myMethod(any(HttpServletRequest.class)).thenReturn(1);
```

`myMethod` is simply:

```java
public Integer myMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return 0;
}
```

In the method I'm testing it's simply called by:

```java
int r = myObject.myMethod(request);
```

But I'm getting:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'myMethod' method:
    mockedObject.myMethod(null);
    -> at somefile.java:160)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. mockedObject.myMethod(null);
      -> at somefileTest.java:68)
```

Comment: Please add the **complete error message** and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: Have you read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139619/simulation-of-service-using-mockito-2-leads-to-stubbing-error ?

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried this because I really wish to keep a high Strictness for my tests.

Comment: You should attach a code where you are invoking method `myMethod`

Comment: It seems it's coming from `any(HttpServletRequest.class)`. I've tried to change `myMethod` to take only one argument which is `HttpServletRequest request`. In the method I'm testing I simply call it by `myObject(request)`. I've updated my question.

Comment: 1. `myMethod` or `todo` method!;)? 2. `any(Class clazz)` [*doesn't match* `null`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-) ! (-> `request == null`?;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was because my value was null and `any()` was not working on null arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any-java.lang.Class-) **`any(myClass)` doesn't work if the provided argument is null, only `any()` does** as explained [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#any--). In my case, `request` was null so `any(HttpServletRequest.class)` couldn't catch it.
I fixed it by changing

```java
when(mockedObject.myMethod(any(HttpServletRequest.class)).thenReturn(1);
```

to this if you are sure it will be null

```java
when(mockedObject.myMethod(null)).thenReturn(1);
```

or to this if you want to catch all cases

```java
when(mockedObject.myMethod(any())).thenReturn(1);
```

Another method is to use `ArgumentMatchers`:

```java
when(mockedObject.myMethod(ArgumentMatchers.<HttpServletRequest>any())).thenReturn(1);
```

Thanks @xerx593 for the explanation.

Comment: There is a new `isNull` ArgumentMatcher too that would fix this this, as noted `any` is for non-null parameters, `isNull` is now for null params

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nullable(MyClass.class)` to accept either `null` or given type.

This is the earliest appearance I think (v2.5.0), but is also available in Mockito 3, and in the latest (v5.8.0)

- https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.5.0/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#nullable(java.lang.Class)

However, it is unlikely that you have unused `HttpServletRequest request`, so to avoid NullPointerException, you may want to mock it instead of allowing it to be nullable in the Test.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, method's arguments are not matching with the actual method.
Yes, you can use any but that is not a good practice. You should explicitly use the argument that you are using in the actual method.