# PotentialStubbingProblem solved by moving a class. How does it work?

Tags: java, mockito

Here's an MRE:

```java
package com.example.mockitomre;

public interface DocumentedEndpoint {
    EndpointDetails getDetails();
}
```

```java
package com.example.mockitomre;

public interface EndpointDetails {
    String getPath();
}
```

```java
package com.example.mockitomre;

public interface EndpointSieve {
    boolean isAllowed(DocumentedEndpoint endpoint);
}
```

```java
package com.example.mockitomre;

import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;

public class EndpointSieveConfig {
    public EndpointSieve errorPathEndpointSieve(GatewayMeta gatewayMeta, AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher) {
        return endpoint -> gatewayMeta.getIgnoredPatterns().stream()
                .noneMatch(ignoredPattern -> antPathMatcher.match(ignoredPattern, endpoint.getDetails().getPath()));
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.mockitomre;

import lombok.Getter;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
public final class GatewayMeta {
    private List<String> ignoredPatterns;
}
```

```java
package com.example.mockitomre;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ErrorPathEndpointSieveTest {
    private final EndpointSieveConfig endpointSieveConfig = new EndpointSieveConfig();
    @Mock
    private GatewayMeta gatewayMetaMock;
    @Mock
    private AntPathMatcher antPathMatcherMock;
    private EndpointSieve errorPathEndpointSieve;

    @Test
    void doesntAllowIgnoredPatterns() {
        String ignoredPattern = "/ignored-path/**";
        String anotherIgnoredPattern = "/*/another-ignored-path";
        when(gatewayMetaMock.getIgnoredPatterns()).thenReturn(List.of(
                ignoredPattern, anotherIgnoredPattern
        ));

        String pathToExclude = "/ignored-path";
        String anotherPathToExclude = "/it-is/another-ignored-path";

        when(antPathMatcherMock.match(ignoredPattern, pathToExclude)).thenReturn(true);
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match(anotherIgnoredPattern, anotherPathToExclude)).thenReturn(true);

        DocumentedEndpoint endpointToExclude = mock(DocumentedEndpoint.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(endpointToExclude.getDetails().getPath()).thenReturn(pathToExclude);

        DocumentedEndpoint anotherEndpointToExclude = mock(DocumentedEndpoint.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(anotherEndpointToExclude.getDetails().getPath()).thenReturn(anotherPathToExclude);

        String okPath = "/another-ignored-path/on-second-thought-it-is-not";
        DocumentedEndpoint endpointToKeep = mock(DocumentedEndpoint.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(endpointToKeep.getDetails().getPath()).thenReturn(okPath);

        errorPathEndpointSieve = endpointSieveConfig.errorPathEndpointSieve(gatewayMetaMock, antPathMatcherMock);

        assertThat(errorPathEndpointSieve.isAllowed(endpointToExclude)).isFalse();
        assertThat(errorPathEndpointSieve.isAllowed(anotherEndpointToExclude)).isFalse();

        assertThat(errorPathEndpointSieve.isAllowed(endpointToKeep)).isTrue();
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-mre</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>mockito-mre</name>
    <description>mockito-mre</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

So here's the problem: once I run the test, I get

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.PotentialStubbingProblem: 
Strict stubbing argument mismatch. Please check:
 - this invocation of 'match' method:
    antPathMatcherMock.match(
    "/ignored-path/**",
    "/it-is/another-ignored-path"
);
    -> at com.example.mockitomre.EndpointSieveConfig.lambda$errorPathEndpointSieve$0(EndpointSieveConfig.java:8)
 - has following stubbing(s) with different arguments:
    1. antPathMatcherMock.match(
    "/*/another-ignored-path",
    "/it-is/another-ignored-path"
);
      -> at com.example.mockitomre.ErrorPathEndpointSieveTest.doesntAllowIgnoredPatterns(ErrorPathEndpointSieveTest.java:37)
Typically, stubbing argument mismatch indicates user mistake when writing tests.
Mockito fails early so that you can debug potential problem easily.
However, there are legit scenarios when this exception generates false negative signal:
  - stubbing the same method multiple times using 'given().will()' or 'when().then()' API
    Please use 'will().given()' or 'doReturn().when()' API for stubbing.
  - stubbed method is intentionally invoked with different arguments by code under test
    Please use default or 'silent' JUnit Rule (equivalent of Strictness.LENIENT).
For more information see javadoc for PotentialStubbingProblem class.

    at org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher.match(AntPathMatcher.java:195)
    at com.example.mockitomre.EndpointSieveConfig.lambda$errorPathEndpointSieve$0(EndpointSieveConfig.java:8)
```

I don't know what exactly Mockito wants from me, but I made some experiments and it's not about

1. mocking the same method with different arguments;
2. the fact that the method is also called with set of arguments not involved in any stubbing.

```java
// here, Mockito is fine with calling match("/ignored-path/**", "/it-is/another-ignored-path")

    @Test
    void doesntAllowIgnoredPatterns() {
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/ignored-path")).thenReturn(true);
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match("/*/another-ignored-path", "/it-is/another-ignored-path")).thenReturn(true);

        antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/ignored-path");
        antPathMatcherMock.match("/*/another-ignored-path", "/it-is/another-ignored-path");

        antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/it-is/another-ignored-path");
    }
```

You know what helps (beside ditching Mockito's extension, I hate it, it brings more problems that it solves)? Making `EndpointSieveConfig` a nested class of `ErrorPathEndpointSieveTest` like so:

```java
package com.example.mockitomre;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ErrorPathEndpointSieveTest {
    private final EndpointSieveConfig endpointSieveConfig = new EndpointSieveConfig();
    @Mock
    private GatewayMeta gatewayMetaMock;
    @Mock
    private AntPathMatcher antPathMatcherMock;
    private EndpointSieve errorPathEndpointSieve;

    @Test
    void doesntAllowIgnoredPatterns() {
        String ignoredPattern = "/ignored-path/**";
        String anotherIgnoredPattern = "/*/another-ignored-path";
        when(gatewayMetaMock.getIgnoredPatterns()).thenReturn(List.of(
                ignoredPattern, anotherIgnoredPattern
        ));

        String pathToExclude = "/ignored-path";
        String anotherPathToExclude = "/it-is/another-ignored-path";

        when(antPathMatcherMock.match(ignoredPattern, pathToExclude)).thenReturn(true);
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match(anotherIgnoredPattern, anotherPathToExclude)).thenReturn(true);

        DocumentedEndpoint endpointToExclude = mock(DocumentedEndpoint.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(endpointToExclude.getDetails().getPath()).thenReturn(pathToExclude);

        DocumentedEndpoint anotherEndpointToExclude = mock(DocumentedEndpoint.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(anotherEndpointToExclude.getDetails().getPath()).thenReturn(anotherPathToExclude);

        String okPath = "/another-ignored-path/on-second-thought-it-is-not";
        DocumentedEndpoint endpointToKeep = mock(DocumentedEndpoint.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
        when(endpointToKeep.getDetails().getPath()).thenReturn(okPath);

        errorPathEndpointSieve = endpointSieveConfig.errorPathEndpointSieve(gatewayMetaMock, antPathMatcherMock);

        assertThat(errorPathEndpointSieve.isAllowed(endpointToExclude)).isFalse();
        assertThat(errorPathEndpointSieve.isAllowed(anotherEndpointToExclude)).isFalse();

        assertThat(errorPathEndpointSieve.isAllowed(endpointToKeep)).isTrue();
    }

    public class EndpointSieveConfig {
        public EndpointSieve errorPathEndpointSieve(GatewayMeta gatewayMeta, AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher) {
            return endpoint -> gatewayMeta.getIgnoredPatterns().stream()
                    .noneMatch(ignoredPattern -> antPathMatcher.match(ignoredPattern, endpoint.getDetails().getPath()));
        }
    }
}
```

Now it passes! The questions:

1. What does Mockito want from me?
2. Why does making that weird change make Mockito happy?

No, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139619/simulation-of-service-using-mockito-2-leads-to-stubbing-error) doesn't help

### Anything that doesn't address moving the class is **not** an answer to this question. Stop the "duplicate" nonsense please and actually read the question

To those suggesting [Javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/exceptions/misusing/PotentialStubbingProblem.html): it's not a reliable source of information. I literally pasted the code from there, and it *doesn't* trigger `PotentialStubbingProblem`, it triggers `UnnecessaryStubbingException`

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MockitoTest {
    @Mock
    SomeClass mock;
    @Test
    void test() {
        //test method:
        Something something = new Something();
        given(mock.getSomething(100)).willReturn(something);

        //code under test:
        Something something2 = mock.getSomething(50); // <-- stubbing argument mismatch
    }

    abstract class SomeClass {
        abstract Something getSomething(int arg);
    }

    class Something {}
}
```

Comment: Have you read the error message fully, and have you checked the suggested documentation? It says "For more information see [javadoc for PotentialStubbingProblem class](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/exceptions/misusing/PotentialStubbingProblem.html)". To me, that looks like everything you need to know.

Comment: @k314159 the Javadoc didn't help me one bit

Comment: @JensV no, it does not

Comment: @k314159 I suggest *you* read my question carefully. I specifically addressed that theory and even included a code snippet. Why can't you just reproduce it already? Why is SO so insistent on MREs if no one cares to run them

Comment: If I copy paste your code, I get: "Cannot mock/spy class tests.GatewayMeta
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - final class" – maybe that's the reason and your version of Mockito shows a different error message? But why are you even mocking a data-only class?

Comment: FWIW the test passes here, once the `GatewayMeta` class is made non-final. (mockito-core:4.5.1)

Comment: Are you sure that other answer doesn't work for you? Have you tried adding `lenient()` to your `when` calls? The other answers in there also provide some insight into why mockito is behaving that way

Comment: @knittl I withdraw my upvote of your comment: making it non-final actually doesn't make a difference, I checked

Comment: @JensV of course, `lenient()` helps, but it's not what my question is about

Comment: `gatewayMeta.getIgnoredPatterns().stream()` will result in you getting two strings since you write: `thenReturn(List.of(ignoredPattern, anotherIgnoredPattern))` You really want to pass **two different** lists to `thenReturn` over there. (Or really have two different `errorPathEndpointSieve`)

Comment: Typo in my previous comment: I meant "two different `gatewayMetaMock`"

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat why would I want to pass two different lists? The method indeed should return two strings. I don't see a problem here

Comment: Then you should mock the return values for calls to `antPathMatcherMock.match` with the arguments `ignoredPattern, anotherPathToExclude` and `anotherIgnoredPattern, pathToExclude` since those will get called as well in your code. Tl;DR your code is calling the method with arguments you haven't mocked it for.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat then why doesn't this code throw (I included it in the question, but no one seems to notice it): `when(antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/ignored-path")).thenReturn(true);
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match("/*/another-ignored-path", "/it-is/another-ignored-path")).thenReturn(true);

        antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/ignored-path");
        antPathMatcherMock.match("/*/another-ignored-path", "/it-is/another-ignored-path");

        antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/it-is/another-ignored-path");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, let's agree on terminology [Strictness in Mockito
#769](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/769)

> Strictness in Mockito can have 2 forms:
>
> - Strict stubbing that requires that all declared stubs are actually used
> - Strict mocks, that require all non-void methods to be stubbed before they are called
>
> Future direction:
>
> - strict stubbing on by default, opt-out available
> - strict mocking off by default, opt-in available

In your case, we are asking talking strict stubbing behaviour.

strict stubbing is turned on implicitly in DefaultMockitoSessionBuilder:

```java
Strictness effectiveStrictness = this.strictness == null ? Strictness.STRICT_STUBS : this.strictness;
```

Let's turn on STRICT_STUBS explicitely for 2 mocks:

- one created via `@Mock` and MockitoExtension
- one created via Mockito.mock

```java
@Mock(strictness = Mock.Strictness.STRICT_STUBS)
private PathMatcher pathMatcherMock;

private PathMatcher pathMatcherMock = Mockito.mock(PathMatcher.class, withSettings().strictness(org.mockito.quality.Strictness.STRICT_STUBS));
```

The goal is to have the mocks as similar as possible - without implicit defaults.

**Problem 1: Mockito.mock version does not throw PotentialStubbingProblem**

Inspection of the mock's `CreationSettings.stubbingLookupListeners` shows that they are empty. [DefaultStubbingLookupListener](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/219350728d0f1bad9739bfa054074d6c43f1bdb1/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/junit/DefaultStubbingLookupListener.java) is a listener responsible for throwing `PotentialStubbingProblem`, and its code is never executed.

IMHO this is confusing and poorly documented (maybe a bug?).

**Problem 2: @Mock version throws PotentialStubbingProblem, but moving of code to test file resolves PotentialStubbingProblem**

Inspection of the mock's `CreationSettings.stubbingLookupListeners` shows that they contain a `DefaultStubbingLookupListener`

The code responsible for this behaviour is again in [DefaultStubbingLookupListener](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/219350728d0f1bad9739bfa054074d6c43f1bdb1/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/junit/DefaultStubbingLookupListener.java#L75)

```java
private static List<Invocation> potentialArgMismatches(
        Invocation invocation, Collection<Stubbing> stubbings) {
    List<Invocation> matchingStubbings = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Stubbing s : stubbings) {
        if (UnusedStubbingReporting.shouldBeReported(s)
                && Objects.equals(
                        s.getInvocation().getMethod().getName(),
                        invocation.getMethod().getName())
                // If stubbing and invocation are in the same source file we assume they are in
                // the test code,
                // and we don't flag it as mismatch:
                && !Objects.equals(
                        s.getInvocation().getLocation().getSourceFile(),
                        invocation.getLocation().getSourceFile())) {
            matchingStubbings.add(s.getInvocation());
        }
    }
    return matchingStubbings;
}
```

**Follow up:**

**rationale for strict stubbing**

Please read:

- [Strictness in Mockito #769](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/769)
- [Clean tests produce clean code - strict stubbing in Mockito](http://blog.mockito.org/2017/01/clean-tests-produce-clean-code-strict.html)

And again, lets differentiate strict stubbing from strict mocks.

**Your test**

In your test you fall in the case where you dont want strict stubbing - you want the default answer for cases not explicitely mentioned. This is the case where you should use lenient mock.

I would argue that mocking `AntPathMatcher` is not a great solution at all - I would use real class instead.
The behaviour of `AntPathMatcher` is well defined, and the class is easy to instantiate. By mocking, you can easily create the cases where real `AntPathMatcher` matches, but the mock does not.

Using a mock with `PathMatcher` would be less confusing, but I would still recommend using real class.

**No strict stubbing errors in test file**

This is confusing and poorly documented, but unfortunately necessary.

Mockito has no record - replay phases for stubbing, as found in some other frameworks. Stubbing makes an actual call on the mock object.

Without this condition, stubbing would fail

```java
interface Foo {
    String myMethod(String x);
}

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Mock(strictness = Mock.Strictness.STRICT_STUBS)
    Foo foo;

    @Test
    void testFoo() {
        Mockito.when(foo.myMethod("a")).thenReturn("1");
        Mockito.when(foo.myMethod("b")).thenReturn("2");

        System.out.println(foo.myMethod("a"));
        System.out.println(foo.myMethod("b"));
    }
}
```

The above runs cleanly, but would throw `PotentialStubbingProblem` on first call of `foo.myMethod("b")` if source file condition is removed.

**Mockito.mock version does not throw PotentialStubbingProblem**

I raised [MockSettings.strictness() not observed #3262](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/3262) - I think it is a bug

Comment: Thank you for your research! But I still don't understand: 1) what was Mockito pissed about exactly if strict mocks are disabled by default (indeed, as shown in one of my code snippets calling the method with unstubbed args is actually fine)? 2) what is the rationale behind not throwing the exception if the invocation is inside the test class's nested class? "We assume it's test code" – so?.. I just don't follow Mockito's train of thought

Comment: Also, I want to admit that I relied on the assumption that Mockito's mocks return default values (such as `false` for boolean methods) for non-stubbed invocations. That's why I stubbed only the cases when the method should return `true`. Can I somehow tell Mockito: "Here are the stubs, anything else, return defaults"? Or, "...return this"

Answer (score 1):

The crux here comes from the fact that "strict stubbing" is active by default in the juniper Mockito extension.

Referencing the [PotentialStubbingProblem](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/exceptions/misusing/PotentialStubbingProblem.html) docs here (emphasis not mine):

> PotentialStubbingProblem is thrown when mocked method is stubbed with some argument in test but then invoked with **different** argument in the code. This scenario is called "stubbing argument mismatch".

Basically this means that, by their definition of a "clean" test, if a mocked method is called with anything other than predefined arguments and return values, an error is thrown, as that might imply that there's a case the developer forgot to handle when creating the stub.

There's two ways to go about this:

1. Enabling lenient mode (the default for mockito-core), way to do this are illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52139619/simulation-of-service-using-mockito-2-leads-to-stubbing-error)
2. Making sure all potential argument variations are covered. Make sure to not define mocked values that will never be called, as that constitutes a potential error as well.

The second variant can be implemented by adding the following line before any other `when` statements:

```java
when(antPathMatcherMock.match(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(false);
```

---

To verify this, I created an even smaller MRE, following the same general code structure:

Libraries:

```
junit:junit:4.13.2
org.mockito:mockito-core:5.9.0
org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:5.9.0
```

Supplementary file `Matcher.java`

```java
import java.util.List;

public interface Matcher {
    boolean match(String pattern, String subject);

    interface Sieve {
        boolean isAllowed(String str);
    }

    class SieveConfig {
        Sieve create(Matcher matcher, List<String> patterns) {
            return str -> patterns.stream().noneMatch(pattern -> matcher.match(pattern, str));
        }
    }
}
```

File `StubbingProblemTest.java`

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class StubbingProblemTest {

    @Mock
    private Matcher matcherMock;

    @Test
    public void testPatterns() {
        String p1 = "/foo/*";
        String p2 = "/bar/*";
        String s1 = "/foo/123";
        String s2 = "/bar/123";
        String s3 = "/baz/123"; // keep

        List<String> patterns = new ArrayList<>();
        patterns.add(p1);
        patterns.add(p2);

        // Without this line, PotentialStubbingProblem is thrown
        when(matcherMock.match(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(false);
        when(matcherMock.match(p1, s1)).thenReturn(true);
        when(matcherMock.match(p2, s2)).thenReturn(true);

        Matcher.SieveConfig sc = new Matcher.SieveConfig();
        Matcher.Sieve sieve = sc.create(matcherMock, patterns);

        Assertions.assertFalse(sieve.isAllowed(s1));
        Assertions.assertFalse(sieve.isAllowed(s2));
        Assertions.assertTrue(sieve.isAllowed(s3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer does not answer the original question: why PotentialStubbingProblem is solved by moving a class.

Comment: Thank you, but why doesn't this code throw: `when(antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/ignored-path")).thenReturn(true);         when(antPathMatcherMock.match("/*/another-ignored-path", "/it-is/another-ignored-path")).thenReturn(true);          antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/ignored-path");         antPathMatcherMock.match("/*/another-ignored-path", "/it-is/another-ignored-path");          antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/it-is/another-ignored-path");`? Here, I invoke the method with unstubbed args too

Comment: Also, if `PotentialStubbingProblem` relates to strict mocks mandating the stubbing of all non-void method calls on a mock [**which are disabled by default**](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/769), why is it thrown at all? Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: *"why doesn't this code throw"* Oh, I get it. It's because the invocations are now in the same source file, right? Though, I don't understand why it should matter, in Mockito's opinion

Answer (score 1):

*Before you read, I suggest you give Lesiak a credit by upvoting [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77943037/23299948). Below is basically just a recap, but it was him who actually solved this mystery*

Here's in short what happened

Mockito's idea of a clean test (enforced by `MockitoExtension` that I included) involves writing stubbs that **precisely match** what is invoked on its mocks. Importantly, `when(mock.foo(1))` and `when(mock.foo(2))` are considered *two different stubbings*. To be more specific, Mockito expects that:

1. All stubbs are used. *Offences punishable by `UnusedStubbingException`*

```java
void test() {
    // bad
    when(mock.foo(1)).thenReturn("something");
    mock.foo(2);
}
```

```java
void test() {
    // good
    when(mock.foo(1)).thenReturn("something");
    mock.foo(1);
}
```

```java
void test() {
    // also good
    when(mock.foo(any())).thenReturn("something");
    mock.foo(2);
}
```

2. All invocations on a mock are stubbed. *Offences punishable by `PotentialStubbingProblem`*.

```java
void test() {
    // bad
    when(mock.foo(1)).thenReturn("something");
    mock.foo(1);
    mock.foo(2);
}
```

```java
void test() {
    // good
    when(mock.foo(1)).thenReturn("something");
    when(mock.foo(2)).thenReturn("something else");
    mock.foo(1);
    mock.foo(2);
}
```

```java
void test() {
    // also good
    when(mock.foo(any())).thenReturn("something"); // more general first
    when(mock.foo(2)).thenReturn("something else"); // more specific second
    mock.foo(0);
    mock.foo(1);
    mock.foo(2);
}
```

Note the last snippet. *It's* how you specify default return values for Mockito's mocks. I, on the other hand, figured Mockito's mocks would simply return default values (such as `false` for boolean methods) so I stubbed only `true` cases. Wrong!

*However*, there's an exception to the rule. For a reason [I don't fully comprehend](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/discussions/3263) (the comment below doesn't tell me the whole story), Mockito turns off the second requrement **if the invocations are in the same source file as the stubbings**. That's why this doesn't throw

```java
    @Test
    void doesntAllowIgnoredPatterns() {
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/ignored-path")).thenReturn(true);
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match("/*/another-ignored-path", "/it-is/another-ignored-path")).thenReturn(true);

        antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/ignored-path");
        antPathMatcherMock.match("/*/another-ignored-path", "/it-is/another-ignored-path");

        antPathMatcherMock.match("/ignored-path/**", "/it-is/another-ignored-path");
    }
```

That's also why making `EndpointSieveConfig` a nested member of the test class helps

Here's Mockito's code that performs the check (discovered by Lesiak). It could be found in the `org.mockito.internal.junit.DefaultStubbingLookupListener` class:

```java
private static List<Invocation> potentialArgMismatches(
        Invocation invocation, Collection<Stubbing> stubbings) {
    List<Invocation> matchingStubbings = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Stubbing s : stubbings) {
        if (UnusedStubbingReporting.shouldBeReported(s)
                && Objects.equals(
                        s.getInvocation().getMethod().getName(),
                        invocation.getMethod().getName())
                // If stubbing and invocation are in the same source file we assume they are in
                // the test code,
                // and we don't flag it as mismatch:
                && !Objects.equals(
                        s.getInvocation().getLocation().getSourceFile(),
                        invocation.getLocation().getSourceFile())) {
            matchingStubbings.add(s.getInvocation());
        }
    }
    return matchingStubbings;
}
```

I fixed my test by replacing

```java
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match(ignoredPattern, pathToExclude)).thenReturn(true);
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match(anotherIgnoredPattern, anotherPathToExclude)).thenReturn(true);
```

with

```java
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match(any(), any())).thenReturn(false);
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match(ignoredPattern, pathToExclude)).thenReturn(true);
        when(antPathMatcherMock.match(anotherIgnoredPattern, anotherPathToExclude)).thenReturn(true);
```